# How to connect JProfiler with application running on multiple docker container?

Tags: docker, boot2docker, jprofiler

I would like to connect to applications running on docker containers through JProfiler agents and check the performance of application, but I am struggling to connect JProfiler to applicatios processes running on docker.

I am using boot2docker on mac ox. Anyone had any experience with such connections ?

Will be grateful for any tips.